# Count entries that belong to specific type

Tags: sql, postgresql

Lets say I have a database called `people`:

That has `id` and `type`

How can i **count** the people that **belong to specific types**.

I dont want to have a query like this one, i want to automate this:

```
SELECT 
         COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 'single' THEN 1 END) as single,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 'married' THEN 1 END) as marrried,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 'kids' THEN 1 END) as kids
         ......
FROM people;
```

How can I do that? THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use group by

```
SELECT COUNT(id), type FROM people GROUP BY  type
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest technique to yours that gives the right result would be:

```
  SELECT
   SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'single' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as single,
   SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'married' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as marrried,
  ...
```